# He was tired because he worked for six hours

Tags: grammar, past-perfect, past-simple

What sentence would you use in a casual conversation if you just wanted to convey the fact? Is the first one okay or not?

1. He was tired because he worked for six hours.
2. He was tired because he had been working for six hours.

Comment: If you change (1) to _he had worked_, either is possible.

Comment: Please explain, "he had worked" and both (1) and (2) are okay, or "he had worked" and (2)?

Comment: (1) is OK _if_ you change _he worked_ to _he had worked_. The tiredness happened after the work.

Comment: In conversation (in the US) #1 is fine, too. People often do without the past perfect when context is clear.